# Generate 997 Acknowledgement File using BizTalk getting Error

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-mapper

I am facing issue while generate 997 acknowledgement file Using BizTalk. I have X12 811 Consolidated Service Invoice/Statement and I have successfully inserted into database.
But I need to generate acknowledgement file for same for it in EDI format.

Here is my configuration.

[image]

- Send port configuration

[image]

- Send port filter configurations.

[image]

**- while converting into XML it is working fine Xml generate successfully. but while generating EDI file it throw below error.**

Agreement Resolution based on the context properties for x12 Protocal has failed
[image: Error: Agreement Resolution based on the context properties for x12 Protocal has failed.]

- Context property of message

[image]

[image]

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: Yes it is programming question for Biztalk with EDI file

Comment: it is Microsoft Biztalk tool that is used to load File in system. and all Screenshort is configurations of Biztalk

Comment: ok, so where is the programming part?

Comment: I think there is some cofusion here it please look it https://niharmalali.blogspot.com/ this artical i have flow this artical currently

Comment: @Vega BizTalk is a mixture of configuration, GUI interfaces both in configuration and programming, and also pure programming aspects.  So it is on topic for Stackoverflow, even when it is mainly the configuration part.

Comment: Check the context properties of the failed message on the send port and compare that with the agreement settings including parties.

Comment: I hope you don't consider commande-line and sever configuration script as programming cc@Dijkgraaf

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I have add the context property can you please help me into it now

Comment: Have you checked the party information against the Agreement? I see a BTSGuestParty for PartyName, is that what your agreement is set up with?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Can you please help me to set up in agreement? becuase i have not more idea about it. Also i am have add X12 fallback setting for this i am not create any Party yet.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - Is there any update on it i am also create New Party but it is always take BTSGuestParty i don't know how to changes the party for the File so Please help me out into this

Comment: In you receive pipeline do you have a component that resolves the party?